# Can't intent in new activitys

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-intent

I'm creating a file explorer synchronize with an ftp directory.
I have recently adapted my app to work with both internal and external storage, and then I encounter an embarrassing issue. When I try to open a file using this function to intent a new activity:

```
    private fun openFile(file: File) {
        val myMime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton()
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)

        val mimeType = myMime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(file.extension)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
            val fileURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID.toString() + ".provider", file)
            intent.setDataAndType(fileURI, mimeType)
        } else {
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), mimeType)
        }
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
        try {
            context.startActivity(intent)
        } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "No app found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
```

It thow me this error:

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/4B07-EB9F/Android/data/fr.frd.calvezdocs/files/CalvezDocs/ok/lol
```

I think it's related to my path provider, because when I try to open a file on the internal storage it simply work. Here it is but as you can see it's full, I don't know if a path is missing.

Here's my path provider:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-files-path
        name="files_root"
        path="/" />

    <external-path
        name="external_storage_root"
        path="Android/data/${applicationId}"/>

    <external-path
        name="external"
        path="." />
    <external-files-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
    <cache-path
        name="cache"
        path="." />
    <external-cache-path
        name="external_cache"
        path="." />
    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

Someone have an idea?

Thanks

Comment: Please tell Android version of used device.

Answer (score 2):

> > /storage/4B07-EB9F/Android/data/fr.frd.calvezdocs/files/CalvezDocs/ok/lol....

That is a path on a removable micro sd card.

FileProvider normally cannot handle such a path.

For not to high Android versions you can add to xml file:

```
<root
    name="root"
    path="." />
```

For devices with higher Android versions you should make your own content provider to serve from micro sd card.

It's not much code to do so.

Comment: Ok thanks for yout answer do you know any exemple of this kind of code? I’m on android 9

Comment: On Android 9 you can use the root tag i think. Now didnt you try already?

Comment: Ok fixed, instead of <root I'd set     <root-path and it seems to work. I don't really like the fact that this is a temporary solution but for the moment it's working... Thanks !